# Exclude modified by and created by from search results in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

Is it possible to exclude the properties "Modified by" and "Created by" from the search results? Usually I would go to "Edit Crawled Property" and then uncheck the box "Include in full-text index, but it's greyed out. Any hint or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

By default they are mapped to an **ows_Created_0x0020_By** and **ows_Modified_0x0020_By** **crawled properties**.

I think you could remove this mapping. If this doesn't work you can delete the Managed Property itself, although I would avoid this if you can.

[image]

In addition, you can try to open the ows_Created_x0020_By crawled property, and uncheck the box “**Include in full-text index**”. Then , do the same for ows_Modified_0x0020_By.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deleted the "Mappings to managed properties" for both fields but without any effect. I will try to use PNP Modern Search to solve this requirement. https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/ If it works well I'll post an answer.

Comment: Hi, lex. Thanks for your reply. Wish you all the best!